# I need to count how many times elements of y appear in elements of x using R:

Tags: r, for-loop, stringr

"""I need to add a column to dataframe x indicating the number of times an element of y appears in the "animal" column of x:"""

```
library(stringr)

x <- data_frame(c("cat", "dog", "cat and dog"))
colnames(x) <- "animal"
x$count <- 0

y <- data_frame(c("cat", "dog"))
colnames(y) <- "animals"

for (j in length(y$animals)){
  for (i in length(x$animal)){
    if(str_detect(x$animal[i],y$animals[j])==TRUE){
      x$count[i] = x$count[i] + 1
    }
  }
}
```

"""The count column in x should read 1, 1, 2."""

Comment: `str_count` is a function in `stringr` I believe. No need for looping

Comment: simply `str_count(x$animal, paste(y$animals, collapse = '|'))`

Answer (score 0):

The `grepl` function returns a logical value that can be summed. `sapply` is the R equivalent of a loop:

```
x$count <- sapply( x$animal, 
                      function(z){ sum( sapply(y$animals, 
                                            function(zz){ grepl(zz, z)}))})
> x
# A tibble: 3 x 2
       animal count
        <chr> <int>
1         cat     1
2         dog     1
3 cat and dog     2
```